# How many different triples $f : A\to S, g : B \to S, h : C\to S$ are there such that $f , g, h$ are all injective, and $f(A) = g(B) = h(C)$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

In this Question we know that the $|A|,|B| ,|C|=m>0$ and set $S$ has cardinality $n>0.$

Since the functions are one-to-one this means each domain maps a codomain and as all three sets (Domain) have same cardinality we can deduce that ${}_nC_m$  possible codomain mapped by these functions.

And because these functions are One-One, so each function can form ${}_nP_m$ number of One-One function so according to me this leads me to ${}_nP_m/{}_nC_m$  as number of different triples that can be formed.

Can anyone please verify my answer ??

(Ps: I think both my answer and way of questioning is wrong so apologies beforehand)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun Thank You I'll try to improve this question

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega$ represent *one* of the ${n \choose m}$ subsets of $S$ of size $m$.

There are precisely $m!$ different injections that map a set of size $m$ into $\Omega$. This means the number of required triples $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ whose image is $\Omega$ equals $(m!)^3$

But since each candidate for $\Omega$ yields an entirely distinct triple $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ we see there are ${n \choose m}(m!)^3$ possible triples.